# Should I scale the entire canvas with CSS or should I resize every image with relative values?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to have a full-screen canvas, and I wanted to resize it WITH its contents proportionally. I'm debating which of these two methods is better...

1) having everything with pixel-based values then simply scaling the entire canvas with css if the window gets resized...

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 canvas.width = 1280;
 canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
 var sizeCanvas = function(){
   scale = window.innerWidth/1280;
   canvas.style.transform = 'scale('+ scale + ')';
   canvas.height = window.innerHeight/scale;
 }
 sizeCanvas();
 window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
   sizeCanvas();
 });
 function loop(){
   window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0,1280,300);
 }
```

OR
2) drawing the canvas at window.inner size constantly, and resizing every image with relative values to the canvas width and height

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var sizeCanvas = function(){
   canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
   canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
 }
 sizeCanvas();
 window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
   sizeCanvas();
 });
 function loop(){
   window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height/4);
 }
```

I have a lot going on the canvas, so I guess performance is probably the biggest priority

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) This is primarily a matter of opinion, and so off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you are doing more than just drawing an image, I would choose the second option. However you may want to do the resize part like this: 

`setTimeout(function() {
  sizeCanvas();
  addEventListener('resize', sizeCanvas, false);
}, 15);`  **MDN quote**: *Since resize events can fire at a high rate, the event handler shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM modifications. Instead, it is recommended to throttle the event using requestAnimationFrame, setTimeout or customEvent**

Comment: @enxaneta I guess there is a typo in your comment, adding an event listener after a timeout is definitely not the way to throttle an event :-)